# Counter variable does not increase

Tags: c#, list, foreach

Trying to make a `int Variable` that stores the current `position` of a `list<string>`.
Outside my `Foreach` cycle i created the `variable` called cont and i said that its `= 0`, everytime the `cycle` is running it should i`ncrease the value by 1` of the `cont variable` but how can i not pass the first value of the list since it starts as 0 and goes straight to 1.

here is a code snippet of everything needed(With my try included):

```
if (BarCode.Contains(";"))
{
    int cont = 0;
    List<string> list = BarCode.Split(';').ToList();
    List<string> list2 = OBS.Split(';').ToList();
    List<string> list3 = OBS2.Split(';').ToList();

    int sizeList1 = list.Count;
    int sizeList2 = list2.Count;
    int sizeList3 = list3.Count;
    if (sizeList1 == sizeList2 && sizeList1 == sizeList3)
    {
        foreach (string l in list)
        {
            cont = +1;
            Etiqueta = l;
            OBSm = list2[cont];
            OBS2m = list3[cont];
            this.Print(printerName, this.PrintMultiples);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `cont++` or `cont = cont + 1`. You are currently doing `cont = +1` which is equivalent to `cont = 1`.

Comment: Alright thank you two.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `cont = +1;` use `cont += 1;` or `cont ++;`

You are assigning 1 since `+1` is the same as `1`.

Comment: Thank you Mr.Tim Schmelter. Upvote and accepted once i can accept.